# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to do a simple connection with XAMPP and sql server. but when ever I try to enter data or connect to the database, I get this error.what is the error? I badly need it for my project. I don't know why php line 9 is error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\last1\new\register.php:19

```
    <?php
    /* Registration process, inserts user info into the database 
       and sends account confirmation email message
     */

    // Set session variables to be used on profile.php page
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['lastname'];

    // Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
    $first_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $last_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    $hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

    // Check if user with that email already exists
    **$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());**

    // We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
        header("location: error.php");

    }
    else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

        // active is 0 by DEFAULT (no need to include it here)
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, hash) " 
                . "VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";

        // Add user to the database
        if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

            $_SESSION['active'] = 0; //0 until user activates their account with verify.php
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // So we know the user has logged in
            $_SESSION['message'] =

                     "Confirmation link has been sent to $email, please verify
                     your account by clicking on the link in the message!";

            // Send registration confirmation link (verify.php)
            $to      = $email;
            $subject = 'Account Verification ( clevertechie.com )';
            $message_body = '
            Hello '.$first_name.',

            Thank you for signing up!

            Please click this link to activate your account:

            http://localhost/login-system/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash;  

            mail( $to, $subject, $message_body );

            header("location: profile.php"); 

        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
            header("location: error.php");
        }

    }
```

Please help me :( Thank you guys ;*

Comment: have you established a connection to the database?

Comment: Where is $mysqli declared? Is it in another file and if so is it included? And are those double asterisks in your code or just in this question to highlight a line?

Comment: I'll send it to you so you can check it out. What is your email?

Comment: $mysqli is declared in db.php.

Answer (score 0):

`$mysqli->error()` should be `$mysqli->error` because `error` is a property, not a method.

Comment: I changed it but this is what it shows "No database selected" :(

Comment: @G.Caps well, did you ever connect to your db server and select the database? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: what is your email so you can check it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$mysqli->error` instead of `$mysqli->error()`

**Source:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I changed it but this is what it shows "No database selected" :(

Comment: Hey there can i see code where you declared the $mysqli variable

Comment: If you didn't declared that , then it will not work,if it is another file , include that file using `include("mysqli.php");`

Comment: Can you help me ? please .. :(  What is your emai? I'll send it to you

Comment: did you declared the $mysqli variable? I cant post email here because i am new to thia form and don't know much rules

Comment: Where shoukd i declare it? Do you have a gmail?

Comment: Please Visit the above link and fix your Code

Comment: <?php
/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>

Comment: write the database name in $db ='dbName';

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`$mysqli->error`

and not `$mysqli->error()`

Comment: I changed it but this is what it shows "No database selected" :(